# Reduce area below text baseline in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, fonts, baseline

I want to reduce the area below the baseline of certain text in my Flutter app. The space below can be seen here:
[Space below baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU8yV.png)

The text will always be numbers so it will never extend below the baseline. Here is an example of that for reference:
[Letters that extend below baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBrZZ.png)

Is there a way to take up this space so the Divider at the bottom is closer to the bottom of the numbers?

I have tried StrutStyle widget but because I am using an AutoSizeText widget, this is a little hard to get working reliably.

Is my only option to find an uppercase-only font that has less space below the baseline? Or make a custom font myself (which I do know how to do, but is a pain)?

Answer (score 3):

I faced your problem and came up with a solution.

You can use `BaseLine` widget. [How to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0o_RYgWy9k)
And put `baseline = style.fontSize`

Example code:

```
Baseline(
        baseline: _style.fontSize,
        baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: _style,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
      )
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

But please notice every lower case like **jgq**. My solution is just for uppercase only.